# FileNotFoundException (Could not load file or assembly) thrown when using a .NET standard library in a full trust win32 component of UWP app

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I'm having my domain logic in a .NET standard library. I'm trying to use it in a full trust win forms tray component defined in an UWP application. My domain logic library is referenced in both the UWP project and the win forms project.
Now if I start the win forms app as full trust process in system tray and call the domain logic it throws a FileNotFoundException saying it cannot find the nuget packages added in my 'domain logic' library. However if I start the forms app separately, it gets executed properly. As per the answer, I have added copy task in post build event and the copied dlls are included in the project as well.

Here's a [sample repo](https://github.com/Kumara-Krishnan/UWP-Systray) to reproduce the mentioned problem. The readme file contains brief explanation to reproduce the issue. How to fix the FileNotFound being thrown?

Here's the exception trace.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DIServiceProviderSingleton' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at DomainLogic.DIServiceProvider..ctor()
   at DomainLogic.DIServiceProvider.DIServiceProviderSingleton..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DomainLogic.DIServiceProvider.get_Instance()
   at SystrayComponent.SystrayApplicationContext.PerformDomainLogic(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Initially the nuget package dlls were not copied to the bin folder of SystrayComponent. I fixed it by following the workaround posted [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/410#issuecomment-323130308). Even after that I'm getting the mentioned exception.

Since debugger cannot be attached to the win32 counterpart, I've logged any exception thrown in app sandbox localstate file 
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\UWPwithSystrayextension_brppa21vfw7f4\LocalState\Log.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to including the exe file, you also need to include the `DomainLogic.dll` file.

Please find the `DomainLogic.dll` file in `UWP-Systray-master\SystrayComponent\bin\Debug` and add it to the `Win32` folder.

After adding, "Include in the project" in Visual Studio.

Thanks

Comment: I've updated the question. Now I'm getting a FileNotFound when there's any nuget package referred in the library. I've also copied them to the win32 folder post build and included in the project as well.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that you have solved this problem, or is it still not working after copying the dll?

Comment: Sorry, I did not reproduce the problem. When I click on `Perform domain logic`, there is no error message. You can try to clean the solution and regenerate it. (Or download your project from github as a new project and run it)

Comment: Have you pulled the latest commit? It'll be generated in log file in C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Packages\UWPwithSystrayextension_brppa21vfw7f4\LocalState\Log.txt

Comment: In this case, it is caused by the mismatch between the version of the referenced nuget package and the version of the dll file used. In the `DomainLogic` project, the referenced `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is the version of 3.1.3, and the dll is 3.1.0. Just You need downgrade it. But even if this problem is solved, you still need to add other referenced dll files, which is a bit too complicated. It is currently recommended that you write the code in the class library in the Windows Form project, and consider the migration after the project is completed

Comment: How to check the version of generated dll? I guess its the same since in package manager its showing as 3.1.3. Even if i copy the entire bin folder to the win32 folder. Its throwing the same exception.

Comment: I dont get the last part "It is currently recommended that you write the code in the class library in the Windows Form project, and consider the migration after the project is completed"

Comment: Sorry i didn't make it clear, I got the version result based on the error message. The error message clearly indicates that the referenced dll is inconsistent with the dll version used by the assembly. At present, you are dealing with some logic code by creating a .Net Standard 2.0 class library. I mean, you can create a folder in the WinForm project to store these codes instead of creating a new class library. Or you can consider the UWP app to call this part of the code

Comment: I want the library to be shared between uwp and forms app. Also I want this code to be run in forms app to offload cpu usage from uwp app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211117/discussion-between-razor-and-richard-zhang-msft).

Comment: Hi, In theory, you can put all the dlls referenced by all the libraries into the Win32 folder, and it will work as well. However, as you introduce more nuget packages, different nuget packages may refer to different dlls, which is a very large workload
Even the Desktop-Bridge project is mainly based on the UWP project. The main work will be carried out in UWP. You may consider adjusting the software architecture to use some UWP platform functions (such as BackgroundTask). Or create a win32 application, and then convert to Desktop-Bridge application